# like and dislike button with counter (using only html javascript php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am creating a website where a user can create posts. For each post that is made, there should be a like and dislike button. A user must only be able to like or dislike the post, not both

This is my php for getting the content of the post, amount of likes etc from the database.

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die ("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
                
$q = " SELECT Posts.content, Posts.time, 
                Users.screenname, Users.dp, Likes.totallikes, 
                Dislikes.totaldislikes, Posts.repost, Posts.original, 
                Posts.originaltime     
        FROM Posts 
            INNER JOIN Users ON (Users.username = Posts.author) 
            LEFT JOIN Likes ON (Posts.postid = Likes.postid) 
            LEFT JOIN Dislikes ON (Posts.postid = Dislikes.postid) 
        ORDER BY Posts.time DESC limit 100";

$result = $db->query($q);
            
?>
```

every time a user makes a post, this is what is in used in the html file to display the post and the likes and dislikes under it

```
<div>
    <h4><?=$row["screenname"]?> posted:</h4> //this all works great and shows up 
    <p><?=$row["content"]?></p>
    <p class="time"> <?=$row["time"]?> </p>
</div>

<div class="row"> //like button 
  <div class="column">
      <p><button onclick="clickCounter()" id = "like" type="button">like <i class="fa">&#xf087;</i></button></p>
      <div id="result"><?=$row["likes"]?></div>
  </div>

  <div class="column"> //dislike button
      <p><button onclick="clickCounter1()" id = "dislike" type="button">dislike <i class="fa">&#xf088;</i></button></p>
      <div id="result1"></div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that whenever a new post is made, I can only like the most recent post and show the amount of likes or dislikes on that only, when i press the like button on the other posts they only update it on the most recent post. How can I make sure that the like and dislike buttons on all the posts created by the users show their own individual likes and dislikes?
I know I need to get the totallikes from my database for each individual postid but i am not sure how.

this is my js file that I think is wrong for what I am trying to do but I am very new to html, js and php so I do not know how to fix it?

```
function clickCounter() {
    document.getElementById("like").style.backgroundColor = "pink";

    var clicks = 0;
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount + " likes";
    }
}


function clickCounter1() {
    document.getElementById("dislike").style.backgroundColor = "pink";

    var clicks = 0;

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount1) {
            localStorage.clickcount1 = Number(localStorage.clickcount1)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount1 = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount1 + " dislikes";
    }
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You're not storing the like/dislike in the database anywhere, just in localStorage. First, try solving this in a very basic way, with a like link instead: `<a href="/api.php?action=like&postid=<?= $row["postid"] ?>">Like</a>` In your api.php, get the action and postid, then update the db accordingly and redirect back to the post. Once you have that working, you can move to an ajax implementation.

Comment: thank you, I was just trying to edit it and I see that it was done. Sorry about that, I will follow proper indentation from now on.

Comment: You are using the same id multiple times (I guess since it's not 100% obvious from the code you shared) which is invalid html and that's why you can only update the first buttons. You must create unique ids and send them to your function when you call it in order to be able to update the correct button. Also i don't see any code that updates your likes and dislikes in your database.

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou yes I realized it was likely something about the id for the like button, is there anyway to change it and the function for each post? I cannot do it manually because I would need to constantly create different id's and functions for each user post. Likes.totallikes contains the likes from the database,  I am unsure how to use it in the html though.

Comment: There are countless other ways to select elements in JavaScript, it does not always have to be by ID. Often times, it makes sense to make use of the position of / relationship between elements in the DOM, to find the _proper_ element(s) that you want to manipulate.

Comment: Like CBroe said you don't have to use IDs to find which divs you have to update and you still have to figure out how you will update your database (probably through AJAX) so you will have to revisit all your js code. If after you figure the database part still have issues updating the correct divs update your answer and we'll be here to help you

Comment: @ChrisG I don't think allowing requests that will change data to be made over `GET` (a simple link as you said) but it's rather recommended to use a form with `POST` method to send the request, maybe then that form submission can be intercepted to allow `AJAX` to take place. Also, I think there should be a way to authorize that request otherwise respond with a `401` status for example.

Comment: @ths I agree obviously, but OP is a beginner and needs to learn the basics first. Good practice and security concerns can always enter the picture later.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes you're right, but I think putting the OP on the right track is better for him to really understand how the web works and what are the potential threats even for a relatively simple task like what he has.